# Can Rapunzel use her hair to heal herself?

Tags: disney, tangled

My question has two parts:

1. In *Tangled*, before Flynn Rider cuts off her hair, is there any reason why Rapunzel shouldn't be able to use her powers to heal herself?
2. If Rapunzel **can** use her powers to heal herself, doesn't that make her effectively immortal as long as her hair remains uncut?

Comment: Woah, _spoilers_!!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I assumed 5 years was past the statute of limitations for spoilers :-\

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 14):

Within the main canon of films and novelisations there's no indication that she can heal herself. She's certainly *aging* despite regularly singing so there's no major reason to imagine that the other powers would also work on her. On the other hand, her skin is utterly without blemish (despite walking around for hours without wearing shoes) which could imply that her healing function is autonomic, like Wolverine's.

---

This is conflicted by the game "Disney Infinity" in which Rapunzel's [Healing Aura](http://disneyinfinity.wikia.com/wiki/Rapunzel) doesn't just work on those around her but also confers a healing bonus **onto herself**, suggesting that she can heal major injuries if the need arises.